# In Microsoft Outlook 2016, immediately mark an new email as read

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

In Outlook 2016 and in Folder view Pane, when I receive a new e-mail and I'm reading it as follows:

[image]

It's not immediately marked as read until I click on another e-mail or I press `CTRL+Q`.

How can I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the seconds it takes to mark a message as read. Setting this value to `0` will mark them immediately, as you want - see this link for a detailed how-to:

https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/instantly-mark-messages-read-outlook

Comment: Thank you! That's what I needed

Answer (score 1):

In Outlook:

1. Click File
2. Click Options
3. Click Mail
4. Check "Mark items as read when viewed in the Reading Pane"
5. Set "Wait" to zero
6. Click OK

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed! I didn't choose your answer because it wasn't the first and also to encourage the new user, but of course you got +1.